# One 2 Class Example and multiple choice question answer different?

Tags: probability, computer-science, machine-learning, regression, bayesian

I select one **example** from my notes (this is multiple choice) as follows:

Question and Parameters attached to my solution is present as following image:

[image]

but when I plot these as the interval of $x$ is differ from above calculation, why?

[image]

and the answer option of multiple choice for this question is quite differ:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You started working with the assumption that $ 0 \le x \le 1$.

Notice that $\frac{8-\sqrt{76}}2 < 0$ and $\frac{8 + \sqrt{76}}2 > 1$.

$$\left[ \frac{8-\sqrt{76}}{2}, \frac{8+\sqrt{76}}{2} \right] \cap [0,1]=[0,1]$$